# My boss wants everyone to call him boss.

Tags: communication

My boss wants everyone to call him boss.  We work in an office setting and it's just weird?  Am I right?  I can't do it

Comment: It largely cultural.  In Korea it is completely normal to refer to other staff by their title.  In North America from a North American it would be odd.

Comment: There is no question.

Comment: If, when you look back on your working life on the day of your retirement, you find that this is the weirdest thing that ever happened to you at work - if that happens - you should consider yourself a lucky lucky person.

Answer (score 7):

Oh, it's weird alright. At least to me.

Having said that, you ignore the wishes of your boss at your own peril.  I'm not kidding when I say that there could be negative ramifications because of his annoyance with you.  You could get worse assignments or just a cold shoulder.

Of course, if he does hold it against you, would you even want to work there?

On the other hand, maybe he just has a weird sense of humor that is very, very, very dry, i.e. he thinks something funny that isn't.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't seem weird to me, I guess it's a location thing. But even when I was in New Zealand it was normal enough to call the boss 'Boss' rather than by his first name, it was a sign of respect.

It would seem weird to me to call him 'C.E.O' or 'Managing Director'

> I can't do it

It's a petty thing to complain about and refuse to do.

Comment: Here while it could be normal maybe 40-50 years ago, nowadays it is odd to do that, and petty to ask for that.